# Office 365 SSO external DNS redirect

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, single-sign-on, adfs, microsoft-office-365

I have ADFS and office 365 completely set up and configured for SSO, using an ADFS server and ADFS proxy.

For internal users, I have IIS configured on the adfs server to redirect companynamemail.com to http://Outlook.com/owa/companyname.com so that the users, instead of having to go through portal.microsoftonline.com, type in thier user name, click the link, and then login, they just go to companynamemail.com, and it performs the SSO

I'm trying to find a way for external users to have a similar expeirence, I know that they will have to login because they arent authenticated through the domain, but I want thier portal to be companynamemail.com. I tried using the adfs proxy to do the http redirect, but it forwards without allowing them to login and gives an error.

I'm thinking about writing the redirect into the default website, but I'm wondering if I can do it with a redirect or a/cname record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple...

If your public DNS host provides forwarding you can simply create the base A record and have it forward to `portal.microsoftonline.com`.

If you don't have this ability just setup a simple new website on your public facing web servers or even proxy servers that hosts that domain name.  Once you have that you can setup the IIS Rewrite Module to redirect requests to the Microsoft portal and it should do what you want.

We did this as well to provide a "customized" URL for users to access, not to mention any laptops could store the URL and it would work internally and externally, just with different authentication mechanisms.

Sample Rewrite:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&whr=<YOUR FEDERATION SERVER>&wreply=https:%2f%2foutlook.com%2fowa%2foffice365.com%2f?exsvurl=1&ll-cc=en-US
```

[image]

Comment: unless I am mistaken, A records can only point to an IP, so it would have to be a CNAME, and the url for SSO is http://Outlook.com/owa/companyname.com and a cname cant point to subdirectories like that.

Comment: I have it working using a auto redirect off of the default website on the proxy server. And I'm thinking that that is the only way to successfully accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it is. The Redirect from the DNS host is a feature of the DNS host and host specific in most cases.

Comment: @MattBear No problem, O365 for Enterprises is a beast to get going, it took me about 6 months to fully research and test the entire product before rolling it out to our pilot users.

Comment: I'm coming into a kind of reverse enviroment, o365 was set up prior to my arrival, with no local AD. And I'm under a time constraint to get us up to date.

Comment: actually, it looks like a cleaner way of doing is is to just use Outlook.com/owa/companyname.com on the redirect, for both external and internal.

Comment: @MattBear That may be correct. We implemented well before Outlook.com was handling O365 traffic. I was an early beta tester.

Comment: I just talked with my contact on the o365 SSO support team, he told me that they just recently added in silent redirect. So it is new.